# Авторизация в системе с помощью ВК (Android)

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, сервер, вконтакте, авторизация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как авторизоваться в системе с помощью социальной сети. Я не могу найти какой-то подробной информации о том, как это правильно сделать.
Имеется сервер Java + Spring (Tomcat) и мобильное приложение Android. Вопрос заключается в том, как правильно построить механизм авторизации? 
Я могу с помощью SDK от ВК авторизовать пользователя на мобильном устройстве, да, но что это мне даёт? Как авторизовать его в системе? 
Авторизация в ВК даст мне какой-то токен? Который я отправлю на свой сервер, а сервер должен проверить валидность этого токена с помощью того же API от ВК? Где об этом можно почитать? Скажите, как вы решали подобные задачи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь есть несколько возможных решений. Я бы сделал как-то так:

1. На мобиле юзер авторизуется в ВК, получая `access_token`.
2. Отсылает токен на сервер.
3. Сервер по токену получает профиль юзера с API ВК.
4. Проверяет есть ли такой юзер в БД по его `id` в ВК.
5. Если нет - создаёт юзера в своей БД, прописывая его `id` в ВК в поле таблицы юзеров.
6. Если юзер такой уже есть или его только что создали - генерирует для него свой токен по логину (например `id` в ВК) и паролю (пусть это будет случайная строка, генерирующаяся при создании юзера)
7. Отсылает на мобилу сгенерированный свой токен.
8. Мобила пишет его в `SharedPreferences` и использует для запросов к серверу.

В итоге для юзера это будет выглядеть как логин через ВК, а у вас будет на сервере вся его доступная инфа из ВК, возможность логинить юзера по логину и паролю и все запросы к вашему серверу будут красиво требовать токена.

Comment: VK возвращает access_token - но он действует только с устройства пользователя.
Я сейчас столкнулся с такой же проблемой. и не знаю как её решить без направления пользователя в браузер

Comment: @undermuz, да, есть такая проблема. Пути решения два - авторизовывать через браузер или все данные получать на девайсе и передавать их на сервер. По мне так оба варианта плохи. Однако для юзера будет приятнее второй вариант, т.к. не надо браузер запускать.